# C# TCP Connection to Siemens S7 PLC - Network Newbie

Tags: c#, network-programming, port, plc

I want to establish a two-way communication setup between a PC and a s7-PLC.
So far I've been successful setting this up one-way with the use of an open source driver found here:
https://github.com/killnine/s7netplus

This driver allows me to tell the PC to fetch data from the PLC, and also write data. But the problem is I want to setup an onChanged event for specific PLC data, and the only way to currenly acheive that is to frequency poll the PLC's data until I notice it has changed.

I would like it to be more interupt driven, so the PLC sends a signal to the PC asychronously when its data has changed, allowing a faster response, and less network traffic.

So I found Siemens Open Communication Wizard, to basically configure a connection on the PLC side that can be referenced in the PLC code. I have setup the connection so the PLC is passive and looking for Port 2000:

[image]

Now on my c# side, how would I establish connection, just using a socket?

```
// open the channel
_mSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

_mSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);
_mSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 1000);

IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 2000);
_mSocket.Connect(server);
```

I'm really new to netowrking. If the PC is the active partner and I establish connection, I want to asychronously be able to accept data from the PLC,
if I setup a socket.BeginRecieve() somewhere, can I still actively commuincate over the socket from PC->PLC or would it be stuck waiting in the BeginRecieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but now  there is a better tool than s7netplus.

Take a look to: **Snap7** - [Step7 Ethernet Communication Suite](http://snap7.sourceforge.net/)

Excellent tool LGPL3 by Davide Nardella.

> **Overview**
>
> Snap7 is an open source, 32/64 bit, multi-platform Ethernet
>   communication suite for interfacing natively with Siemens S7 PLCs. The
>   new CPUs 1200/1500, the old S7200, the small LOGO 0BA7/0BA8 and
>   SINAMICS Drives are also partially supported.
>
> Although it has been designed to overcome the limitations of OPC
>   servers when transferring large amounts of high speed data in
>   industrial facilities, it scales well down to small Linux based arm or
>   mips boards such as Raspberry PI, BeagleBone Black, pcDuino,
>   CubieBoard, UDOO and ARDUINO YUN.
>
> Three specialized components, Client, Server and Partner, allow you to
>   definitively integrate your PC based systems into a PLC automation
>   chain.

Comment: I looked into Snap7 a while back, the "Partner" setup seemed like it was exactly what I needed. But I couldn't figure the code out, I wish they had some more documentation or even a clear example of how to use Partner would be nice.

Comment: Take a look at the website; you have an excellent doc and examples.  Also use the Wiki; Davide is always ready to help and give advice to every post on the wiki.